# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED for file upload

Tags: node.js

I am following a tutorial on file upload from w3School
https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_uploadfiles.asp

When I tried to set the path to my Desktop, it does not work

app.js

```
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req,res){

    if(req.url == '/fileupload'){
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(req,function(err,fields,files){
            console.log(err);
            var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
            console.log(oldpath);
            var newpath = 'C:/Users/usr/Desktop/' + files.filetoupload.name;
            fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function(err) {
                if(err){
                    throw err;
                }
                res.write('File uploaded and moved');
                res.end();
            });
        });
    }else{
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write('<form action = "fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
        res.write('<input type = "file" name = "filetoupload">');
        res.write('<input type = "submit">');
        res.write('</form>');

        return res.end();
    }
```

Error:

```
no such file or directory, rename '/var/folders/xc/l94jk0vx4cx7v2gf7fytvy600000gn/T/upload_b2ccee4542cc2b2c1e1e1475848284e2' -> 'C:/Users/usr/Desktop/Screen Shot 2018-04-19 at 2.41.23 PM.png'
```

I could not find out the issues. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So it is a stupid mistake.

For Mac users, you do not have to input the `C:/` in your path. It is just `/Users/usr/Desktop/`